# How to run php unit tests in extention yii2

Tags: unit-testing, yii2, phpunit, codeception

I wont to run unit tests in widget uploaded like extention by composer like https://github.com/lysenkobv/yii2-geoip

After installation an extention it is located in ./vendor/lysenkobv/yii2-geoip ana tests located in ./vendor/lysenkobv/yii2-geoip/tests
How I can run tests in my yii2 app.

I have installed codeception and phpunit in my yii2 app in vendor/bin/

Comment: Why do you want to run tests of third-party extension in your app?

Comment: I want to install it in my app by composer and then run tests 
to make sure that everything works. In addition, I also want to create my extension to the likeness of this. And I want to know how to run tests in this case.

Comment: Is there any reason why you think that tests of this extension may not pass in your environment? Usually extensions are independent and they're tested separately.  Additional testing of already tested extension is only a waste of time and resources.

Comment: hi @SergioCodev , you can use this command "./vendor/bin/codecept run unit {files}"

Comment: Ok. Thanks. This command is it what I finde.

Comment: Thanks  @rob006 . I think this is true.  To make tests  for extention I`ll include separated app (yii2) . If You have an example, please give me link to it.